# Text + image not working with telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Having troubles with sending image with text. Instead of actual image, I'm just getting the path to it. I wonder if someone knows what is the problem in my code. Instead of the path I want an actual image

[image]

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('q1', callback_data ='da')
    item_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("asdas", callback_data = 'net')
    markup.add(item_4, item_3)

    img = r'C:\Python\k123s.jpg'
    text = 'Your profile!'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{text}\n{img}', reply_markup = markup)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def button(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('q1', callback_data ='da')
    item_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("asdas", callback_data = 'net')
    markup.add(item_4, item_3)

    #img = r'C:\Python\k123s.jpg'
    #text = 'Your profile!'

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, open=(r'C:\Python\k123s.jpg', 'rb'), caption="text", reply_markup = markup)
```

PyTelegramBotApi has captions, which lets you add text to photos `caption = 'text'`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `send_message` you need to use `send_photo`.
In your case, the last 3 lines will be:

```
img = r'C:\Python\k123s.jpg'
text = 'Your profile!'
bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(img, 'rb'), caption=text, reply_markup = markup)
```